# Can black make a draw offer?

Tags: etiquette

I am playing a chess game and my opponent is black and he asked me if I would accept a draw since I have a King and a Knight while he has a King and a Bishop. I told him that he can make an offer and he mentioned it's against etiquette when black makes an offer. Can you please lead me to locate the source? The game is on GameKnot.com.

Comment: If random people on third-rate chess sites are making claims about rules and it's not about a weird pawn capture, assume they're lying.

Comment: Your opponent offered you a draw, and you told him that he can offer you a draw, and he said it wouldn't be etiquette for him to offer you a draw? What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such rule.

It would be against etiquette for one side to offer a draw repeatedly, or to offer one in a position which is a certain loss. [FIDE rule](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018) 11.5 lists "unreasonable offers of a draw" as one thing that can constitute distracting or annoying an opponent, which is prohibited.

In an official over-the-board game, the proper time to request a draw is after you've made your move but before you hit the clock (FIDE rule 9.1.2.1.) That seems to be impossible in an online game, so I would say that it would be best to make the offer right before you move, so that the offer notification doesn't come during your opponent's thinking time.

Comment: While this may be obvious, this would not be considered a "certain loss". Checkmate is possible in this situation only if both players work together so the game would draw from fifty moves or threefold repetition.

Comment: What is this etiquette to do with purpose of Chess. Chess has been so heavily moderated by Fide, that Original Chess lost its purpose.. What we play today is fantasized Chess

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim Of course OP's situation is not a certain loss; a loss would be quite unexpected here, and a draw offer is appropriate. But if the opponent had two queens and a bishop vs OP's knight, then OP offering a draw would ordinarily not be appropriate (exceptions include situations where the opponent has a real chance of losing on time, or has made no progress after a large number of moves.)